# Symfony form validation of integer field

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I am trying to use the type validation rule with integer and it fails with some warning.

Here is my form

```
class BusinessType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('business_number', 'integer', array(
            'required' => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

Here is my validation rule

```
My\Bundle\Entity\Business:
    properties:
        business_number:
            - Type:
                type: integer
```

So nothing extravagant!

But I get the following error

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: NumberFormatter::parse(): Number parsing failed"

I already found a work around [here](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=40191&p=130870), but it doesn't feel right to do that. I will if there is no other solution but I prefer to avoid it.

I know it was a known bug in earlier version of Symfony but it is supposed to be fix. See [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/5943).

So is there a way I can use the type validation? And if so, what am I missing?

#### Edit 1

I am using Symfony 2.6.6

#### Edit 2

If my value starts with numbers (like *123dd*), I have the following error message, even if I customized my error message

> This value is not valid.

But if my value starts with something else, I have the error fore-mentioned.

#### Edit 3

The longest value I need to store is 9 digits long. So integer should work properly.

#### Edit 4

Here is the [bug report](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14430)

Comment: Are you trying to input a phone number or an integer? Phone numbers are a terrible thing to store as integers. You have to strip out things like dashes and potentially useful information (what about extensions? How do I express that as an integer?) You should use a text Form Type with regex validation instead, or come up with a custom form type so you can utilize the HTML5 `tel` input type.

Comment: It's an integer I need to store. It's not a phone number.

Comment: Do you get this error when you submit the form and leave the `business_number` blank?

Comment: Nope, it is working properly when blank or null.

Comment: It should be noted that the PR you linked to the Symfony2 repo is for the [`number` Form Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html), not the `integer` one, although the `IntegerToLocalizedStringTransformer` extends the `NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer`. Could you try using a `number` Form Type instead?

Comment: Can you post an example of your `business_number` ? They could simply be too big to be stored as integer...

Comment: @sjagr, I already tried with number and I have the same behavior

Comment: @A.D. you've showed us a failing business_number, can you show us a correct one?

Comment: @Veve, I tried with *123* and it works

Comment: We generally use a custom type, and extend the 'text' type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `integer` and/or `number` Symfony Form Type utilizes the [`Symfony\Component\Intl\NumberFormatter\NumberFormatter::parse` method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.6.6/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/NumberFormatter/NumberFormatter.php#L533) before storing the value to the Form. The contents of the method are as such (as of Symfony 2.6.6):

```
public function parse($value, $type = self::TYPE_DOUBLE, &$position = 0)
{
    if ($type == self::TYPE_DEFAULT || $type == self::TYPE_CURRENCY) {
        trigger_error(__METHOD__.'(): Unsupported format type '.$type, \E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    preg_match('/^([^0-9\-\.]{0,})(.*)/', $value, $matches);
    // Any string before the numeric value causes error in the parsing
    if (isset($matches[1]) && !empty($matches[1])) {
        IntlGlobals::setError(IntlGlobals::U_PARSE_ERROR, 'Number parsing failed');
        $this->errorCode = IntlGlobals::getErrorCode();
        $this->errorMessage = IntlGlobals::getErrorMessage();
        $position = 0;
        return false;
    }
    preg_match('/^[0-9\-\.\,]*/', $value, $matches);
    $value = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.\-]/', '', $matches[0]);
    $value = $this->convertValueDataType($value, $type);
    $position = strlen($matches[0]);
    // behave like the intl extension
    $this->resetError();
    return $value;
}
```

Notably this part:

```
preg_match('/^([^0-9\-\.]{0,})(.*)/', $value, $matches);
// Any string before the numeric value causes error in the parsing
if (isset($matches[1]) && !empty($matches[1])) {
    IntlGlobals::setError(IntlGlobals::U_PARSE_ERROR, 'Number parsing failed');

// ...
```

will cause any malformed entry with a string at the start to throw an Exception.

Unfortunately, changing the validation rules will do nothing as this parsing is run *before* validation occurs.

Your only workaround will be the one you've linked, and to submit a bug report until the problem is fixed. The [current `master` branch doesn't have an update to this file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/NumberFormatter/NumberFormatter.php#L533) and it's unclear if the problem was solved elsewhere (further research would be required).

Front-end validation could also help (for example, the built-in validation for HTML5 `number` and `integer` types will cause most browsers to stop you before submitting to Symfony).

Comment: Thanks. I will do a bug report.

Comment: @A.D. Please do link it here. I may look into it more in my free time.

Comment: I added the link to the bug report in the original message